# How can I suspend multiple threads so that they do not start to process any job and I can restart my windows service?

Tags: multithreading, windows-services

I am new to multithreading. In a windows service I am using SemaphoreSlim class to initiate a Thread Governer. The SemaphoreSlim constructor takes in two arguments - the thread pool size and the maximum thread pool size. I set this as following -

```
int poolSize = 2;
SemaphoreSlim threadGoverner = new SemaphoreSlim(poolSize, poolSize);
```

So the threadGoverner is initialized when the WindowsService is started, that is, the OnStart event. Now these two threads are being used to process some kind of jobs. I have a requirement where I need to change the pool size dynamically. So if the pool size is changed to 3, the service should start processing 3 requests.

So, what I am trying to do is to restart the service using a batch command file. But the problem I am facing is if there are more than 1 threads running, another continues to process these jobs. And that is causing my service to behave abnormally.

What I want is that if I detect a change in the pool size, no thread should start to process a job, so that I can restart the service without any anomaly.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: First thought - why do you need to restart the service? Send it some message that tells it to create/destroy X threads and add/remove X units from the semaphore.

Comment: @Martin James: Thanks Martin. I will try this option.